# True becomes false using SwiftyJson in swift

Tags: swift, swifty-json

I am getting the opposite value of a boolean when using .boolValue 
I have this code.

```
let _ = channel.bind(eventName: "like-unlike-cake", callback:  
  {(data:Any?)->Void in
let likedCake = JSON(data!)["like"]
print("liked cake: \(likedCake)")
print("Boolean: \(likedCake["liked_by_current_user"].boolValue)")

liked cake: {
    "liked_by_current_user" : true
}
}
Boolean: false
```

But when I use .bool it gives me nil. Does someone help me on this.

UPDATE This would be the json I want to fetch

```
{
 "like": {
 "id": "66642122-7737-4eac-94d2-09c9a35cbef8",
 "liked_by_current_user": true
 }
}
```

Comment: It means that property value is nil or wrong parsed. hard to tell it without a full picture of your JSON and output. But when you're using [Non-optional getter](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#non-optional-getter) for Bool value, it will return you false if property is nil

Comment: Can you clear up the discrepancy between `liked_by_current_user` and `likedByCurrentUser`.  If the data is as per the JSON you posted, the real question is why `print("liked cake: \(likedCake)")` prints `"liked_by_current_user" : true` because the key does not exist.

Comment: @livenplay oops sorry. I updated my question.

Comment: use `likedByCurrentUser` key to get boolean, you definitely get `true`

Comment: @Hitesh yes I did that but I am getting nil when I print the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
let _ = channel.bind(eventName: "like-unlike-cake", callback {
   (data:Any?)->Void in

    if let jsonData = data {
         let json = JSON(jsonData)
         let isLikedByCurrentUser = json["like"]["liked_by_current_user"].boolValue
         print(isLikedByCurrentUser)
    } else {
         // your data is nil
         debugPrint("data error")
    }
}
```

also you can try to cast your `data: Any` into `Data` by replacing the line:

```
if let jsonData = data as? Data {
     let json = JSON(data: jsonData)...
```

cause sometimes SwiftyJSON have problems with creating JSON objects from `Any`.

Comment: okay thanks. Im just getting error - initializer for conditional binding must have optional type not json. Thats why I added let json = try? JSON(data: jsonData). Is this the correct way?

Comment: @Jearson ah, sorry, my mistake, updating the answer

Comment: Nothing to sorry about. Im should be the one thankful.

Comment: Im getting the "data error" so meaning there is a problem with my backend side?

Comment: Well, try to print your `data: Any` object, just after `(data:Any?)->Void in` add `print(data)` and if it's `nil`, than something is definitely wrong with your network request or probably with the backend

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150328/discussion-between-livenplay-and-jearson).